# Filtering Date column of dataview using Rowfilter

Tags: ado.net

I want to filter my View according to selected date which is in the format "DD/MM/YYYY", but my dataview column has date in "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss" format.I want to filter the view according to selected date irrespective of time.How do i convert MATCH_DATE column to the format "DD/MM/YYYY" format in RowFilter.

```
dtFixt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "MATCH_DATE='" & CType(calSeason.SelectedDate,DateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the MATCH_DATE column to "DD/MM/YYYY" format in your view, using CONVERT function as follows:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MATCH_COLUMN, 103)
```

103 is a Date Format Code that converts the any date in "DD/MM/YYYY" format.

For more details on different date formats, refer article [Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

Comment: i tried but an error like 'The expression contains undefined function call VARCHAR().' is occuring at runtime @shant.    dtFixt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MATCH_DATE, 103)='" & CType(calSeason.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "'"

Comment: Apologies for not giving you proper instructions but you need to convert the column in your view in the database and not in the code. So your view will change from...

SELECT MATCH_COLUMN, COL1, COL2....

to...

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MATCH_COLUMN, 103), COL1, COL2...

Let me know, if you need more details.

Comment: Tat works fine thanks @shant.but is there a way without changing the View ?

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think that there is another way without changing the View. Reason being that you want the row values to be in specific format and not the conditional value.